# Infinite call renderCell in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using function component to create a MUI dataGrid, and trying to add a button in a column, and I have a onRowClick function to open a side pane when user clicking row. The problem is, once I click row, react will report error:

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Here is the code:

```
 const openViewPane = (params: GridRowParams, e): void => {
        setRightSlidePlaneContent(
            <ViewAccountPane
                close={closeForm}
                params={params}
            />,
        );
        setRightSlidePlaneOpen(true);
    };
const formatDates = (columns): GridColDef[] => {
        return columns;
    };

    const addTooltipsToData = (columns: GridColDef[]): GridColDef[] => {
        console.log('render tool bar called');
        return columns.map((column) => {
            const { description, field, headerName } = column;
            console.log('inside map');
            if (field === ID) {
                console.log('直接return');
                return column;
            }
            return {
                ...column,
                renderCell: (): JSX.Element => {
                    console.log('render run');
                    return (
                        <Tooltip arrow title={description || ''} >
                            <span className={classes.headerCell}>{headerName}</span>
                        </Tooltip>
                    );
                },
            };
        });
    };

    const formatColumns = (columns: GridColDef[]): GridColDef[] => {
        const dateFormatted = formatDates(columns);
        return addTooltipsToData(dateFormatted);
    };


    console.log('generic table rendered');
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <DataGrid
                columns={formatColumns(columns)}
                rows={rows}
                autoHeight
                className={classes.table}
                components={{
                    Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
                }}
                density={GridDensityTypes.Compact}
                filterMode={tableMode}
                hideFooterSelectedRowCount
                loading={loading}
                onFilterModelChange={handleFilterChange}
                onSortModelChange={handleSortChange}
                sortModel={sortModel}
                sortingMode={tableMode}
                onRowClick={openViewPane}
            />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
```

However, if I change the renderCell to renderHeader, it will work fine.

```
    setRightSlidePlaneContent  
    setRightSlidePlaneOpen
```

Above are two state passed by parent component in props. it will open a slide pane.
After I comment setRightSliePlaneOpen, it will work well. But no slide pane show.

Please help me slove it. Or do you know how can I add a button in column not using renderCell?

```
const PageFrame: FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const { Component, userInfo } = props;
    const [navBarOpen, setNavBarOpen] = useState(false);
    const [rightSlidePlaneOpen, setRightSlidePlaneOpen] = useState(false);
    const [rightSlidePlaneContent, setRightSlidePlaneContent] = useState(
        <Fragment></Fragment>,
    );
    const [rightSlidePlaneWidthLarge, setRightSlidePlaneWidthLarge] = useState(
        false,
    );
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: `${GET_USER_LOGIN_INFO}_${REQUEST}`,
            payload: {
                empId: userInfo.empId,
                auth: { domain: 'GENERAL_USER', actionType: 'GENERAL_USER', action: 'VIEW', empId: userInfo.empId},
            },
            meta: { remote: true },
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <HeaderBar
                navBarOpen={navBarOpen}
                toggleNavBarOpen={setNavBarOpen}
            />
            <NavigationBar open={navBarOpen} toggleOpen={setNavBarOpen} />
            <Component
                setRightSlidePlaneContent={setRightSlidePlaneContent}
                setRightSlidePlaneOpen={setRightSlidePlaneOpen}
                setRightSlidePlaneWidthLarge={setRightSlidePlaneWidthLarge}
            />
            <PersistentDrawerRight
                content={rightSlidePlaneContent}
                open={rightSlidePlaneOpen}
                rspLarge={rightSlidePlaneWidthLarge}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default PageFrame;
```

The component that calls setRightSidePlaneOpen

```
interface IProps {
    setRightSlidePlaneContent: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<JSX.Element>>;
    setRightSlidePlaneOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    setRightSlidePlaneWidthLarge: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const TagDashboard = (props: IProps): JSX.Element => {
    const { setRightSlidePlaneContent, setRightSlidePlaneOpen, setRightSlidePlaneWidthLarge } = props;
    const employeeId = useAppSelector((store) => store.userInfo.info.employeeNumber);
    const rows = useAppSelector((state) => state.tag.rows);
    const accountId = useAppSelector(store => store.userInfo.accountId);
    const updateContent = useAppSelector(state => state.tag.updateContent);
    const numOfUpdates = useAppSelector(state => state.tag.numOfUpdates);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const closeAddForm = (): void => {
        setRightSlidePlaneContent(<Fragment />);
        setRightSlidePlaneOpen(false);
    };
 
    const openAddForm = (): void => {
        setRightSlidePlaneContent(
            <AddForm
                category={'tag'}
                close={closeAddForm}
                title={ADD_FORM_TITLE}
                createFunction={createTag}
            />);
        setRightSlidePlaneOpen(true);
    };

    const closeForm = (): void => {
        setRightSlidePlaneContent(<Fragment />);
        setRightSlidePlaneOpen(false);
        setRightSlidePlaneWidthLarge(false);
    };

    const openViewPane = (params: GridRowParams, e): void => {
        setRightSlidePlaneContent(
            <ViewAccountPane
                close={closeForm}
                params={params}
            />,
        );
        setRightSlidePlaneOpen(true);
        setRightSlidePlaneWidthLarge(true);
    };

    // to the RSP.
    return (
        <GenericDashboard
            addFunction={openAddForm}
            description={DESCRIPTION}
            title={TITLE}
            columns={columns}
            handleRowClick={openViewPane}
            rows={rows}
            numOfUpdates={numOfUpdates}
            updateContent={updateContent}
        />
    );
};
```

This is the component of the right slide pane

```
 const { content, open, rspLarge } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();

    const drawerClass = rspLarge ? classes.drawerLarge : classes.drawer;
    const drawerPaperClass = rspLarge ? classes.drawerPaperLarge : classes.drawerPaper;

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Drawer
                className={drawerClass}
                variant='temporary'
                anchor='right'
                open={open}
                classes={{
                    paper: drawerPaperClass,
                }}
            >
                <Fragment>{content}</Fragment>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: It looks like the error might be in code other than what you have provided here. Can you post the code for the RightSlidePlane component?

Comment: it's the state of parent component, I'm so confused why renderHeader can work fine. but updated

Comment: Can you share the full code of the first component (which calls `setRightSlidePlaneOpen`? Or at least more of it?

Comment: Updated the full code. do you have any idea?